# Help with R - funModeling package no longer available, need help downloading older version

Tags: r, statistics, data-science-model

I have posted on GitHub but I'm not getting a response as quickly as I would like so I figured I'd seek help on multiple forums/websites. I am trying to do a few sample mean exercises from a textbook 'Practical Statistics for Data Scientists' and I am stuck trying to use a package on R called funModeling, the latest version is no longer available so I am trying to download an older one.

Currently, the closest I have come is the following:

```
install.packages("funModeling") Warning in install.packages : package ‘funModeling’ is not available for this version of R A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere, see the ideas at https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Then, I go there and into my terminal and I type :

```
R CMD INSTALL -l /Users/ben/Downloads/ "funModeling"
```

Yielding the following error:

```
Warning: invalid package ‘funModeling’ Error: ERROR: no packages specified
```

Where I have a folder 'funModeling' in my /Downloads folder with the following downloaded from the old archives:

[image: funModeling_Folder]

A little new to R but I've run the following:

```
' @importFrom gridExtra grid.arrange

' @importFrom ROCR prediction performance plot

' @importFrom stats cor quantile

' @importFrom RColorBrewer brewer.pal

' @importFrom grDevices colorRampPalette

' @importFrom stats kmeans rbeta hclust cutree dist IQR na.omit sd mad median

' @importFrom utils head tail

' @importFrom moments skewness kurtosis

' @importFrom entropy entropy

"_PACKAGE" [1] "_PACKAGE"
```

i.e. the dependencies and the goal is to draw from loans data and successfully sample means from population distributions, where I have done the following thus far:

```
library(ggplot2) 

library(data.table)

path <- "/Users/ben/Desktop/R_Data_Lives_Here" loans <- readr::read_csv(paste0(path, "/loan.csv"))

library(readxl)

#Load the Excel workbook

excel_file = paste0("/Data_Dictionary.xlsx")

#see available tabs

excel_sheets(paste0(path, excel_file))

meta_loan_stats = read_excel(paste0(path, excel_file), sheet = "LoanStats")

meta_browse_notes = read_excel(paste0(path, excel_file), sheet = "browseNotes")

meta_reject_stats = read_excel(paste0(path, excel_file), sheet = "RejectStats")

meta_loans <- funModeling::df_status(loans, print_results = FALSE) 
knitr::kable(meta_loans)

When I am defining the meta_loans variable I need to use the "funModeling" package and herein lies my error:

'Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘funModeling’
```

Still unable to find out how to get the old package that I can use and I am sure it is a simple fix, I am returning to R after not having used it for awhile and am just getting stuck with these little fundamentals. If you would like more details please let me know. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved with the help of a User from GitHub:

" Hi there, well let's go step by step.
You have to run the following commands inside the R Console.

1- First you need to install dependencies:

```
install.packages(c("Hmisc", "ROCR", "gridExtra", "pander", "reshape2", "lazyeval", "moments", "entropy"))
```

2- Download package from the CRAN Archives and don't unzip it:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/funModeling/funModeling_1.9.4.tar.gz

3- You will have to install it manually:

```
install.packages("C:/path_to_package/funModeling_1.9.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Now you should have funModelling installed and available from R.
Hope being helpful
Good Hacking :) "

I messed up, and ran through the following process:

```
(base) ben@Benjamins-MBP Documents % ls
funModeling_1.9.4.tar
(base) ben@Benjamins-MBP Documents % install.packages("C:/Documents/funModeling_1.9.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
zsh: unknown file attribute: C
```

On the last step and just getting this error, extremely close, what could be causing this problem?

```
(base) Benjamins-MBP:~ ben$ install.packages("C:/Documents/funModeling_1.9.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"C:/Documents/funModeling_1.9.4.tar.gz",'
-ne
```

RESOLVED EDIT: I figured it out with the following:

```
The downloaded binary packages are in
/var/folders/zt/j17k7wr12p35myvz_rgf161h0000gn/T//RtmpZhGUtI/downloaded_packages

install.packages("~/Documents/funModeling_1.9.4.tar", repos = NULL)
Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'

install.packages("~/Documents/funModeling_1.9.4.tar", repos = NULL, type = "source")
installing source package ‘funModeling’ ...
** package ‘funModeling’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
DONE (funModeling)
```

In the end I needed the proper syntax to the file path. Now I can use funModeling for future problems.